# Can I create Cloudwatch custom metrics with Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to create AWS CloudWatch custom metrics using Java SDK provided by AWS?

The developer guide talks about publishing custom metrics through Command line tools.
Is it possible with the Java SDK? If yes, please provide the links or tutorials for that.

Answer (score 6):

The below code can be used to Publish Custom Metrics in AWS CloudWatch using JAVA.

```
AmazonCloudWatch amazonCloudWatch = 
AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("monitoring.us-west-1.amazonaws.com","us-west-1")).build();

PutMetricDataRequest putMetricDataRequest = new PutMetricDataRequest();
putMetricDataRequest.setNamespace("CUSTOM/SQS");

MetricDatum metricDatum1 = new MetricDatum().withMetricName("MessageCount").withDimensions(new Dimension().withName("Personalization").withValue("123"));
        metricDatum1.setValue(-1.00);
        metricDatum1.setUnit(StandardUnit.Count);
        putMetricDataRequest.getMetricData().add(metricDatum1);

PutMetricDataResult result = amazonCloudWatch.putMetricData(putMetricDataRequest);
```

Only thing to remember is to include aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch

Answer (score 4):

Yep, it's absolutely possible to create custom metrics programmatically using the AWS SDK. Here's a link to the CloudWatch client as part of the AWS SDK for Java:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html

If I remember correctly, you just start putting data into CloudWatch using the `putMetricData(..)` method, and it will start showing up (after a short delay of a minute or two).